# Unable to persist the CSS elements on a ASP.NET List Box items

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to add different list items (with different color attributes) to a CheckBoxList in ASP.NET, the items were added to the list correctly with the correct color. However, on a partial update (it's in an update panel), all the attributes were gone.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?
(is this just a view state issue?)

this is how i added the elements to the check list box

```
ListItem newItem = new ListItem(strText);
if(condition)
newItem .Attributes.CssStyle.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Color, "orange");
checkListBoxList.add(newItem);
updatePanelListBox.update();
```

thanks!

Comment: How are you adding elements? client-side via JavaScript? in the code-behind? How are you applying the css styling to the items?

Comment: I am using code behind and adding the attribute manually ... and i've updated the question with code snippets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, when the page Postback, the HTML gets replaced with the response sent by IIS to client`(Client -> IIS WebServer -> ISAPI Extensions -> ISAPI load it/Execute it and send back the converted HTML -> Sends to IIS - > IIS sends back to Client)`. In case of Async PostBack, I assume that your CheckedListBox is inside the Update Panel. When the Page Postback during Async mode, the styles will be removed by the latest CheckedListBox HTML from server and the style implementations will take place during new request again. It's better to store the data in ViewState and assign it across the async postback.

Comment: ok - this is what i've suspected and turning on the "enabled view state" property does not work as well. 
I'll go with the custom implementation then to restore (either at load or data bound) the CSS values unless you know of a better way to handle this.